# Non-contiguous column copy from one spreadsheet to another in google apps

Tags: google-apps-script

How would I format non-contiguous columns to be copied to another sheet? I know (thanks Serge) that you can do contiguous columns with the following!

```
.getRange("A2:C")
```

say I need to do column A, C, K, AD, BB for example.

Is there a simpler way than assigning all columns you need different variables, getting them all individually, and putting them in the sheet you need?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not simpler, but I would say better performance, to get one big range encompassing all the columns you need with `.get(Data)Range().getValues()`, use Javascript to strip down the array to only the columns you need, and use `setValues()` to paste the values in one hit:

```
function copyValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName('Source').getDataRange().getValues();
  values.shift(); //remove header row
  var columns = [0, 2, 10, 29, 53]; //array of zero-based indices of required columns
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
    output[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0, width  = columns.length; j < width; j++) {
      output[i][j] = values[i][columns[j]];
    }
  }
  ss.getSheetByName('Destination').getRange(2, 1, length, width).setValues(output);
}
```

The issue would be if you required copying formats and formulae as well, in which case the best option might be copy-pasting each column individually, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is really a little redundant/academic, as the `=QUERY()` function will allow you to do the what you want. eg `=QUERY(A1:D31,"Select C, A, B")` I've also given an example of using it on the example sheet (linked below). `QUERY` can also be used with `=IMPORTRANGE()` [explanation](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/EGuDUkhtpaI) from @AdamL. I've included that functionality in my function too to demonstrate. Finally, my function can be used in a spreadsheet, or in a script with no modifications. There are examples of using `QUERY(IMPORTRANGE())` and my function `copyColumns` at my [example spreadsheet](http://goo.gl/WSpPZ).

---

I have included some validation so that the function can be used by less technical folks using spreadsheets. Hopefully it's useful to you too. I have made liberal use of JS functionality including [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and the [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) please ask for any clarity you need in the comments here.

The basics: It takes a string of the form `"SheetName!A,C,B"` where the `SheetName!` is optional. And it can take a starting row, with a default of 1. It can also deal with non local spreadsheets by being given a sheetKey (with or without starting row).

For example: `=copyCoumns("MyDataSheet!C,A,W",8)` Will copy the columns C, A and W in that order starting with row 8.

Here's the function! Enjoy!

```
function copyColumns(sourceRange,start,sheetKey) {
  // Initialize optional parameter
  if(!sheetKey && typeof start !== "number") {
    sheetKey = start;
    start = 1;
  } else {
    start = start || 1;
  }
  // Check SourceRange Input
  var inputRe = /^((.*?!)(?=[a-z],?|[a-i][a-z]))?[a-i]?[a-z](,[a-i]?[a-z])*$/i;
  if(!inputRe.test(sourceRange))
    throw "Invalid SourceRange: " + sourceRange;

  // Check Start Row
  if(typeof start !== "number")
    throw "Starting row must be a number! Got: " + start;
  if(start % 1 !== 0)
    throw "Starting row must be an integer! Got: " + start;
  if(start < 1)
    throw "Starting row can't be less than 1! Got: " + start;

  // Get the Source Sheet
  try {
    var ss = sheetKey
           ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetKey)
           : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  } catch(err) {
    throw "Problem getting sheet" + sheetKey + " - " + err;
  }
  var sheetName = sourceRange.match(/^.*?(?=!)/);
  var sheet = sheetName
            ? ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[0])
            : ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Check that everything is still valid
  if(!sheet)
    throw "Could not find sheet with name: " + sheetName;
  if(start > sheet.getLastRow())
    throw "No data beyond row: " + start + " Last row: " + sheet.getLastRow();

  // Get the values
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-start+1;
  var values = sheet.getRange(start,1,lastRow,lastCol).getValues();

  // Get the desired columns from the string
  var desiredColMatch = sourceRange.match(/([a-i]?[a-z](,[a-i]?[a-z])*)$/i);
  var desiredColumns = desiredColMatch[0].toUpperCase().split(",");

  // In case the column we are trying to grab doesn't exist in the sheet
  var lastColId = sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1; // Array is 0 indexed, Sheet is 1

  // Get the numerical values of the passed in Column Ids
  var columns = desiredColumns.map(function(colId){
    var num = colId.length - 1; // 0 or 1
    var colNum = colId.charCodeAt(num)-65+num*26*(colId.charCodeAt(0)-64);
    if(colNum > lastColId)
      throw "Invalid Column: " + colId + " - Column not in: " + sheetName;
    return colNum;
  });

  //Map the values to a new array of just the columns we want
  return values.map(function(row){
    return columns.map(function(col){
      return row[col]
    })
  });
}
```